# MySql - identifying and copying a URL from one field and placing in another

Tags: mysql, search, copy

I have a table called articles with a number of fields. In the content field there is a url. I'd like to copy this url and place it in another field using a query. But I'm havin trouble even just selecting the url. I could do it manually with something like...

```
"this is content http://blah"
```

and then 
`SELECT substring(content, 17, 11) 
FROM articles 
WHERE content LIKE '%http%'`

but is it posible to write a query that would search and find the url for each article? Or would that require me to write my own function? Or would it be a script job?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE url_copy 
SET url = SUBSTRING(
  SUBSTRING(content, POSITION('http://' IN  content)), 
  1, 
  POSITION(' ' IN CONCAT(SUBSTRING(content, POSITION('http://' IN content)), ' ')) -1
);
```

The data i tested with:

```
SELECT * FROM url_copy;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| content                                                     | url                            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
| this is content and http://facebook.com/puggan.se is my url | http://facebook.com/puggan.se  |
| http://puggan.se/                                           | http://puggan.se/              |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```